# How to move the text inside a Qlabel?

Tags: qt

I need to move the text inside a label from right to left.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean you want the text read direction to be from right to left, or you want to align the text to the right of the label or something else entirely?

Comment: Do you want to have animated text moving from right to left?

Comment: Please can you answer the comments above then flag to re-open.

Comment: I need animated text moving from right to left.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the text alignment inside your QLabel, you can use the setAlignment method (example above written in Java):

```
QLabel label = new QLabel("Your text"); // create a new QLabel object
label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight); // align the text to the right
```

According to what you try to achieve, you can use other alignments. See [this page](http://doc.trolltech.com/qtjambi-4.5.0_01/com/trolltech/qt/core/Qt.AlignmentFlag.html) for a list of available values for QLabel alignments.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I need animated text moving from right to left inside the label.